# Is there any API to get Flight details of US Airways and Indian Airways using PHP

Tags: php

Is there any API to get Flight details of US Airways and Indian Airways. Including Flight timings and everything which are all necessary.

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Answer (score 0):

Doing the Google search for you. Have a look at:

[http://flightwise.com/](http://flightwise.com/news/323/Free_XML_Flight_Tracking_API.html?gclid=CLrsyvyJrZ0CFVtm4wodiWObkw)

[http://www.flightstats.com/](http://www.flightstats.com/go/Forum/forumViewForum.do?forumId=10)

Comment: thanks Lace... thanks for your help.. but still i am struggling to get the O/P. Any more hints

Comment: Looks like the flightwise API is in beta only.

The flightstats developer docs are at: https://www.flightstats.com/developers/bin/view/Main/?

It's hard to help if we don't know what you're doing or what particular problem you have.